# Conflict of a jar between two sdk's causing compile time issues

Tags: android, gradle, build, sdk, build.gradle

I am using two sdk's in my app. My sdk is using a compiled obfuscated jar file which is causing conflict with other sdk when add together as dependency in an app.

Due to which I am getting a compile time error as follows

```
Duplicate class a.a found in modules module-core-31.2.5-runtime (com.random1.android.sdk:module-core:31.2.5) and random2-core-4.0.0-runtime (com.abc.xyz:random2-core:5.0.0)
 Duplicate class b.a found in modules module-core-31.2.5-runtime (com.random1.android.sdk:module-core:31.2.5) and random2-core-4.0.0-runtime (com.abc.xyz:random2-core:5.0.0)
```

How to resolve this as this code comes from jar and these SDK's are already compiled?

Answer (score 0):

Class names such as `a.a` or `a.b` look like identifiers generated by obfuscators.

If you're sure both SDKs use the **very same** JAR (in which case I don't see why this would happen), then there are generally two options:

- Leave out this dependency from one of the SDKs:
  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps
- Use a custom class loader based on the *Bootstrap class loader* to which you can add all **unique** resources found by the *System class loader*.

Given that it's a compile time error, you're probably left with the first option only.